# I am getting an error while inserting data into mysql database being new to the tech field searching for someone to me out

Tags: python, mysql

```
with open('housePrice.csv','r') as f:
    data=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\n')
    for lines in enumerate(data):
        for list_ in (lines[1]):
            cursor.execute('insert into testineuron.houseprice values({values})'.format(values=list_))
        mydb.commit()
```

data inside houseprice.csv ->

```
63,1,True,True,True,Shahran,1850000000.0,61666.67
```

error ->

```
ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Shahran' in 'field list'
```

Comment: The values inside of the SQL `values(<here>)` list will need to be quoted if they are string values. `Shahran` is a string so that list should look like `63,1,True,True,True,'Shahran',1850000000.0,61666.67`

Comment: It's also worth noting that someone with access to `housePrice.csv` could put a value of `;DROP TABLE testineuron.houseprice;--` (or similar) in the first column of that csv and destroy your table. If that is a concern, then consider parameterizing that list of values instead of concatenating your sql string together.

Comment: It worked when in added a string to the values thanks for helping me out.